# Curling couchDB with json to update cors

Tags: json, windows, curl, couchdb, cors

i am unable to update cors in my couchDB using curl.

The website says:

```
$ export HOST=http://username:password@myname.iriscouch.com
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d '"true"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/origins -d '"*"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/credentials -d '"true"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/methods -d '"GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE"'
$ curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/cors/headers -d \
  '"accept, authorization, content-type, origin"'
```

I'm on windows so i'm trying:

```
set HOST=http://username:password@myname.iriscouch.com
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d '"true"'
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/origins -d '"*"'
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/credentials -d '"true"'
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/methods -d '"GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE"'
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/headers -d \
  '"accept, authorization, content-type, origin"'
```

progress so far:

```
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d '"true"'
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d 'true'
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d {'"true"'}
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d {"""true"""}
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d true
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"badarg"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d {true}
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d {"true"}
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '"true"'
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d '"true"'
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d {"true"}
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
C:\xData\CiS>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d {"""true"""}
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
```

I just donwloaded curl
i have windows 64bit
trying to change the cors for the purpose of syncing with pouchdb

update:
the next attempt didn't work either:

```
C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d "{\"true\"}"
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (worked for me):

```
set HOST=http://username:password@myname.iriscouch.com
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d "\"true\""
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/origins -d "\"*\""
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/credentials -d "\"true\""
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/methods -d "\"GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE\""
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/cors/headers -d \ "\"accept, authorization, content-type, origin\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning `I'm on windows` Try this:

```
curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d "{\"true\"}"
```

From windows the single quote(`'`) around the parameter value doesn't work. You have to use double quote(`"`).

Comment: Thanks for the response but it that didn't work either.

`C:\xData\CiS>curl -X PUT %HOST%/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d "{\"true\"}"
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}`

Comment: @Matthew I don't have much expertise on JSON, but as far I know it should be in format like `{"some-value": true}` where the `true` goes with a key. You can run your curl command with `-v` parameter and it will show you what are the things curl doing during the operation. For example it successfully pass the JSON to server then it will say `Content-Length: xxx` where `xxx` is a number.